# Groupby Still Counts Values Even After the Rows Have Been Dropped

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, drop

I have a very large dataframe of stock data ranging from 2016 to 2022. When I do analysis on it, I only want to do it on a subset of this data for example only data from 2020 by using a 'drop row' function. The problem I am having when I do the analysis on each individual stock symbol through a 'Groupby' function, the 'Groupby' picks up symbols that were in the original dataframe, but not in the reduced one (ie. the symbol had no data for that year). This causes the 'Groupby' to include null data for these dropped symbols which creates a series that is longer than the reduced dataframe. I am unable to dateframe and series and do further analysis.

You can see from the below pictures of the 'Groupby' key count that, for example, 'AACI' has no data. When I investigate the reduced dataframe 'AACI' is not in it, yet the 'Groupby' picks it up with a count of 0.

Has anyone experienced this before where the 'Groupby' is still picking up values from the original dataframe even though it is being fed a reduced dataframe? Any solutions would be great.

My code

```
file_loc = 'Data\minute_data_2016-22_grp_.feather'
df = pd.read_feather(file_loc)

df['date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date

start = "2020-01-01"
end = "2020-01-12"

start = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
end = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

df = df.loc[(df['date'] >= start) & (df['date'] <= end)]

df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

atr = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(lambda x: ta.atr(x.high, x.low, x.close, 21)).reset_index(0,drop=True).rename('ATRr_21')
```

Original Dataframe
[image: Original Dataframe]

The 'Groupby' row count for each key from the original dataframe

[image]

Reduced Dataframe
[image]

The 'Groupby' row count for each key from the reduced dataframe

[image]

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: maybe you use wrong variable, or maybe you forgot to assign new value to variable. You also use some `ta.atr()` which you didn't show - maybe it uses older data.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on my small data. Maybe create minimal working code which we could run. And it would need some example data in code (or as link to file)